# Youtube data api quota increase

Tags: youtube-data-api

Hi i am writing android app that lets users take videos and upload them to youtube, as of now i am not anticipating any where close to reaching quota since Im still developing the app. But I am worried since the limit is 1,000,000 units per day, I will eventually cross it.

So how do we increase it, I noticed under the quota tab there is an option, clicking it brings up a form. **But it doesn't mention how much will it cost me to increase the limit? Also I couldn't find any google support page so I am asking it here**

thanks

Comment: Can you please share if and how you were able to increase it? Many people are on the same boat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current quota, you can upload near 660 videos a day. If you get close to that number you can fill that form which is a long form and you need two cups of coffee and perhaps more than 2 hours to do it. In around 48 hours, they will send the result and will approve it, if your app behaves compatible with "terms of service". And it's free.

Cheers.

**Edit**

It is not documented anywhere, but very recently (almost since the day I answered this question), YouTube has changed the data-api, that each day it accepts 50 videos, and afterward it accepts only one video per 15 minutes. And because it is just applied without being documented nor explained by YouTube, we cannot anticipate what the limitation is going to be.